# I am getting FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: BM_DPM_Date__c

Tags: apex, soql, batch, query, asynchronous

I am facing the following issue. I wrote this query for the start method of my batch class.

```
global Date startDate;
global Date endDate;
global Date currentDate;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext dbc){
 String queryFields = 'Id, Name, BM_DPM_Date__c, BM_DPM_FC__c, BM_DPM_RecommendedFT_MH__c, BM_DPM_PartTimeMH_Average__c, BM_DPM_ExtraMH__c ';
    String queryObjectAPIName = 'BM_DailyProductivityManagement__c';
    String queryOrderby = 'BM_DPM_FC__c, BM_DPM_Date__c';

    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT ' + queryFields + 'FROM ' + queryObjectAPIName + 'WHERE BM_DPM_Date__c >=: startDate AND BM_DPM_Date__c <=:endDate ' + 
                                    ' ORDER BY ' + queryOrderby);
}
```

I thought everything was okay. But when I run it I got the following Query Exeption:

```
16:54:24:025 EXCEPTION_THROWN [27]|System.QueryException: unexpected token: BM_DPM_Date__c
```

I think I've missed something in my dynamic query string. Please, could you help me find the problem in my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a space just before WHERE. So it should be:

```
'FROM ' + queryObjectAPIName + ' WHERE BM_DPM_Date__c
```

Comment: Thank you so much!